# Hie, am looking for a way to dynamically change listtile text color in flutter as it loads Builder context

Tags: flutter-listview

**if the results of maction='cr' then the text to be one color and if not another color**
If

```
        if (dc = snapshot.data[index].maction) {
            drcr = true;
        } else {
            drcr = false;
        }
                                
        drcr 
        ? snapshot.data[index].maction.instanceof(context, Color.fromRGBO(255, 66, 165, 1))
        : snapshot.data[index].maction.instanceof(context, Color.fromRGBO(155, 66, 165, 1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the Color into a class:

```
Color dynamicColor(bool drcr){
  if(drcr){
    return Color.fromRGBO(255, 66, 165, 1)
  } else{
    return Color.fromRGBO(155, 66, 165, 1)
  }
}
```

Then just plug that into your code:

```
snapshot.data[index].maction.instanceof(context, dynamicColor(drcr))
```

Comment: Joe, the code seem to be correct but its throwing an error of 'String' has no instance method 'instanceof'. I think av messed up. Now, maction is a string returning either 'DR' or 'CR'. av even try using a string instead of a bool since it gave me the same error but nothing. What can you advice

Comment: I have managed after using an int instead of a bool or string. when defining the color I just called dymamicColor(int)